Can odd-power polynomials uniformly approximate continuous functions vanishing at 0 on [0,1]?
Question:
Consider the space of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with $f(0) = 0$. Does the set of polynomials with only odd powers of $x$ (i.e., of the form $P(x) = a_1x + a_3x^3 + \dots + a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$) uniformly approximate every such continuous function $f$?
I suspect the claim is false because:

The set of odd-power polynomials is not a subalgebra (e.g., $x \cdot x^3 = x^4$, which is not in the set).

Is this reasoning correct, or am I missing something?
From previous discussion about it

The simplest argument was provided by @Robert Israel. Another proof could be as follows. Any continuous function $f,$ such that $f(0)=0,$ can be approximated by continuous functions $g$  vanishing on an interval $[0,\delta].$ The functions $h(x)=g(x)/x$ are then continuous, hence they can be approximated by polynomials $p(x)$ involving only even powers of $x.$ Thus $g(x)=xh(x)$ can be approximated by polynomials with  odd powers only.

Ohh I see, nice trick, thank you!
So here the condition $f(0)=0$ made this works, without this condition it will not work?

Any polynomial involving only odd powers vanishes at $0,$ so does the uniform limit of such polynomials.
